# Combine and then count instances of a value with rows being the instance

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, union

I have a table that looks like this

| name | name 2 | name 3 | boolean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jeff smith | rachel smith | kate drew | true |
| rachel smith | jeff smith | leigh fun | false |

and what I want to do is query so the results look like this

| name | count boolean |
| --- | --- |
| jeff smith | 1 |
| rachel smith | 1 |
| kate drew | 1 |
| leigh fun | 0 |

So I am combining the three rows with string text and then counting how many times the boolean is true. I have tried a few ways and have gotten totally wrong results. I'm very much a newbie to this.

I have tried

`SELECT name1, name2, name3, count(case when boolean = true then 1 else 0 end)  from table  group by name1, name2, name3`

`select name1, count(boolean=true) from table  group by name1 union select name2, count(boolean=true) from table  group by name2 union select name3, count(boolean=true) from table  group by name3 order by count desc`

Comment: `I have tried a few ways....` ← Include those attempts in your question as code and what did not work.

Comment: Why do you have 3 columns for the same property? What if you add a 4th name or 100?

Answer (score 0):

What a horrible design. Have *one* column for the name, not three.

You can do that ad hoc in a derived table using `UNION ALL`. Then simply `GROUP BY` and `FILTER` for the `true` flags. But you really should fix that table itself.

```
SELECT name,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE boolean) AS "count boolean"
       FROM (SELECT name1,
                    boolean
                    FROM elbat
             UNION ALL
             SELECT name2,
                    boolean
                    FROM elbat
             UNION ALL
             SELECT name3,
                    boolean
                    FROM elbat) AS x
       GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: But there are three names, so how would I be able to match up the values if they are all in one column? I am SUPER new to this and trying to just learn as I go.

Comment: @LachlanSholls: That depends on what you mean by "match up". Why not ask a new question and describe, in detail, what you want to model with the current table and how to improve this design. (But don't overdo it. Just ask for that *specific* part of the design. Do not ask for a other parts of the model as this quickly becomes too broad for one SO question.)